# Deal with relationships/associations in JSON response using deserializeUntyped

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am parsing JSON returned from a web request using the deserializeUntyped method. The response contains data from a couple of different models and the relationships are arranged as follows:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "posts": {
        "1234567": {
            "newest_reply_at": null,
            "message": null,
            "formatted_message": "<p></p>",
            "has_attachments": true,
            "created_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:06-08:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:10-08:00",
            "reply_count": 0,
            "reply": false,
            "private": false,
            "subject_id": null,
            "subject_type": null,
            "id": "1234567",
            "subject_ref": null,
            "user_id": "098765432",
            "workspace_id": "5556677",
            "story_id": null,
            "google_document_ids": [],
            "attachment_ids": [
                "12345432",
                "09876789"
            ]
        }
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "posts",
            "id": "1234567"
        }
    ],
    "attachments": {
        "12345432": {
            "updated_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:09-08:00",
            "created_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:00-08:00",
            "filename": "Clarizen.key",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "filesize": 542546,
            "url": "https://some_website.com/attachments/12345432",
            "previewable": true,
            "private": false,
            "creator_name": "Test User",
            "id": "12345432"
        },
        "09876789": {
            "updated_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:09-08:00",
            "created_at": "2015-01-15T13:32:00-08:00",
            "filename": "Elevator pitch.rtf",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "filesize": 2431,
            "url": "https://some_website.com/attachments/09876789",
            "previewable": true,
            "private": false,
            "creator_name": "Test User
            "id": "09876789"
        }
    },
    "google_documents": {}
}
```

The data is coming from the newsfeed of a web app and I am sync'ing it with Chatter and trying to preserve file attachments. I will link to the attachments in the Chatter post.

I'm pretty new to Apex and I've been running into mismatch issues between List, Set and Map and I haven't been able to figure out what format things should be in.

So far I have the following:

```
// Parse the response and create a List of Maps to store Post data
Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String,Object> posts = (Map<String,Object>)m.get('posts');
List<Map<String,Object>> returnPosts = new List<Map<String,Object>>();


// Add the posts response to the List of Maps for easier use
for (String p : posts.keySet()) {
    Map<String,Object>  pp = (Map<String,Object>)posts.get(p);           
        List<String>aIdList = (List<String>)pp.get('attachment_ids');
        Set<Map<String,Object>> aList = new Set<Map<String,Object>>();

        if (!aIdList.isEmpty()) {
            for (String aId : aIdList) {
                Map<String,Object> a = (Map<String,Object>)m.get('attachments'); //.get(aId);
                aList.add(a.get(aId));
            }
        }
        returnPosts.add(pp);                
}
```

Everything worked fine before I took into consideration the attachments. Now that I need to preserve the attachments, my logic is as follows:

- Loop through each post cast any "attachment_ids" to a list
- If the list isn't empty (there are attachments associated with the post), loop through each one and fetch the related data from the top level "attachments" node of the JSON.
- I would like to then add the attachment data to the list of posts "returnPosts", perhaps under the key "attachments", with a list of attachments as the value.
- I will then rinse and repeat with "google_documents"

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!